# Querying-friendly domain objects localization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, localization

I need to design an application which stores partially multi-lingual content; i.e. some of the domain objects fields are translatable. 
note: I'm using NHibernate, but this is just a technical detail in the case.

Let's consider the following domain model:

```
public class Post {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual User Author {get; set;}
    public virtual string Title {get; set;} // translatable
    public virtual string Content {get; set;}  // translatable
}
```

Looking through the internet I've found several approaches, most of them hackish and ugly; many completely unacceptable.
Most of the solutions are based on introducing "special" fields to the model, whether it's like `Title_FR, Content_FR, Title_EN, Content_EN` or `Dictionary<string, string> ContentTranslations`.

Pros:

- easy to query (first case)
- performance

Cons:

- requires schema change when adding language (first case)
- requires adding special fields to the model

Later on I've designed my own solution (which, further investigating, happened to be reinventing the wheel) which intercepts the NHibernate-specific events; i.e. once the instance of domain model is populated with values, the translatable fields are re-populated with translated values from abstract translation provider.

Pros:

- seamless integration
- no schema modification
- completely automatic

Cons:

- impossible to query on the translated field; filtering on the translated fields causes strange (from user point of view) behavior

I'm looking for the solution which

1. integrates possibly seamlessly. No special fields introduced to the domain model
2. Applies translations automatically
3. Takes care not to overwrite original values when updating the (translated) domain object
4. is querying friendly; i.e. the introduction of the mechanism doesn't require the LINQ queries to be changed significantly. This probably disqualifies "joinable" translation table
5. ideally, the solution should not break the LINQ projection; this however is probably just asking way too much ( * )

( * ) word of explanation on 5. I'm using AutoMapper's `Project.To()` extensively, to avoid retrieving unnecessary fields and SELECT N+1 problems. 
The solution I've came up doesn't work with projection, I believe `OnPostLoad` event is not fired when using projection

Any recommended reading on the subject?

Comment: what's your DB strucutre?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your DB structure looks like. If you do not want to use IDictionary (which I would prefer), then I would propose implementing a `LocalizableString` class and a corresponding `ICompositeUserType`, `IUserType` or using Component mapping.

```
public class Post {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual User Author {get; set;}
    public virtual LocalizableString Title {get; set;} // translatable
    public virtual LocalizableString Content {get; set;}  // translatable
}
```

You will probably also need to implement some extensions to the linq provider, to allow custom query operations.

---

Some alternative approaches to consider:

- using formula columns formula columns for localized fields
- using my very own [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) to allow queries of the calculated properties.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll have a look into implementing custom type and it's linq extensions. I don't think formula column would help here, as it doesn't allow cross-table query I believe? Also, how would DelegateDecompiler help here? Thanks!